# Why Data disappear after refreshing React JS - Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello there's something I really do not understand because it does not make any sense at all, I have 2 pieces of code that are EXACTLY the same only difference is the variables I use to find the collections and one does persist even after refreshing and the other one doesn't here are the pieces of code:

Students list one:

```
const [estudiantes, setEstudiantes] = useState([]);
  const estudiantesRef = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid).collection("estudiantes")

 useEffect(() => {
  estudiantesRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const tempData = [];
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      tempData.push(data);
    });
    setEstudiantes(tempData);
  })
 }, []);

 console.log(user.uid)
 console.log(estudiantes)
```

Books list one:

```
const [productos, setProductos] = useState([]);
    const productosRef = db.collection('libros');

    useEffect(() => {
        productosRef
        .orderBy('grado')
        .onSnapshot( snapshot => {
            
            const tempData = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

              const data = doc.data();
              tempData.push(data);
            });
            setProductos(tempData);
        })
      }, []);
```

[Gif student](https://media.giphy.com/media/SzPQRAd3B37e5tAKqo/giphy.gif)

[Gif books list](https://media.giphy.com/media/EcnI5YS9g4hhoODSqp/giphy.gif)

Update: The `user.uid` is ALWAYS present regardless of the refresh however the data stored in `estudiantes` disappears when I refresh and that's not good lol. Why does the data disappear ? I test it by only loading 1 collection and it doesn't disappear so why does it disappear when it goes to multiple collections and how I can fix it ?

Before Refresh

[image]

After Refresh

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to clarify that after a week or more of fighting with this issue, the answer wasn't because it was a nested collection

(Nested)
estudiantesRef references: collection > document > collection

(not nested)
productosRef references: collection

it was because the user from my code was being set back to null as soon as you refresh but if you wait like 2 seconds it changes back to his normal value. all I had to do is use user in the array dependency in my firebase useEffect.

However this means that the issue wasn't because it was a nested collection as someone else pointed out. just that, firebase can load data instantly (as long as there aren't that many values clearly) there shouldn't be an issue in loading just 1 piece of information.

Answer (score 3):

The two pieces of code might seem to do *exactly* the same thing, but the reality is, they are not.

`estudiantesRef` references: `collection > document > collection`

`productosRef` references: `collection`

Naturally you'd expect `productosRef` to return faster as it's only doing one lookup, but it also depends on the number of records in each collection, etc. So you should double check this. Also, any additional processing done on the data after retrieval will affect the time it takes to show.

My suggestion is you create a `loading` state (or use `console.log`) to double check you're getting back data when you expect to.

> one does persist even after refreshing and the other one doesn't

Unless you're using something other than `React.useState` to store your state, then the data shouldn't be persisting between refreshes. This could be a result of local caching, or the page just loading quickly.

Comment: estudiantes goes through what? 2 users? and then send the amount of students which in this case is 6. While productos have 40+ maybe more documents it doesn't make sense to me. Loading state? Edit: When I refresh the array shows 0 data so I'm not getting data back. Even though I can SEE the students the `console.log` shows `[]` instead of `array[6]`

Comment: if 'estudiantesRef' is the issue, are you sure 'user.uid' always has a value when you make the call?

Comment: user uid is always present just checked with a console.log, the array of data is the one that just randomly disappears (will attach image)

Comment: Update: I was doing the `console.log` of the wrong Item which is why was showing `[]` and now that I have add the `correct console.log` and is even weirder because I CAN SEE is the right data

Comment: @ReactPotato where have you added the console log? As Kerron pointed out, data doesn't get persisted on refresh if you are just using the code you've provided in the question.

Comment: So what do I do to fix the issue ? When I refresh the data disappears, how do I keep it ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need an answer, but:

For data to be kept on refresh, you should set your items in localStorage

```
const item= localStorage.setItem('keyValue', 'dataToPersist')
```

then get data by:

```
const item= localStorage.getItem('keyValue')
```

Comment: I'm using local data and still lose the data :/ I made a new question because "technically" this one is "Why data...etc" and I got the right answer they told me why it happens but not how to fix, new question is here:  [How to make data persist on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446063/how-to-make-data-persist-on-refresh-react-js)